# Moving parameters for variable to set up - model behaviour changes

Tags: variables, random, installation, netlogo

This one stumping me...

I have an ABM which generates new patients arriving to a hospital unit by random-poisson on a single patch (spout procedure). Each patient is assigned an area to go to and a time to spend in the unit according to the area and other assigned variables. When I created this with the distributions embedded in the procedures or reporters it worked fine every time, but when I code the random variables into the set up to make it easier to manipulate it regularly generates grossly abnormally low/high values (ranges not seen when run in original format) and sometimes the creation of new patients doesn't happen at all though the model still ticks on... The only things changed are the placement of the variables in set up and and not in the body of the code.

I can't figure out why it would randomly have no patients entering the system which makes me mistrusting of anything else it generates. Is this just a formatting style that Netlogo doesn't like? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for any advice/help in solving this one

original code:

```
  if ticks = 1000 [stop]
  ask arrivals                                   
  [
    assess                                       
    crowding-check                               
    relocate                                     
  ]

end

to assess      

  sprout-patients random-poisson 1.5                                                  
    [set time_arrived ticks                                                           
     set condition random-float 1.0                                                   
     set NEWS2 random-float 7.0                                                       
     set shape "person"
  ]

end

to-report AEC_treatment_time ;; gamma dist                                           

  let result random-gamma 3.478 0.525                                                

  if result < 2  [ report 2 ]                                                        
  if result > 20 [ report 20]

  report result

end

to-report AMU_treatment_time ; gamma dist                                            

  let result random-gamma 5.7716 0.3                                                

  if result < 4  [ report 4]
  if result > 48 [ report 48]

  report result

end
```

new code:

```
  ca


  set new-patients random-poisson 1.5

  set AEC-los random-gamma 3.478 0.525
  set AMU-los random-gamma 5.7716 0.3


  reset-ticks

  end

to go
  if ticks = 1000 [stop]
  ask arrivals                                   
  [ 
    sprout-patients new-patients
    assess                                       
    crowding-check                               
    relocate                                     
  ]
 end

to assess                                                                             

  ask patients-here
     [set time_arrived ticks                                                           
     set condition random-float 1.0                                                   
     set NEWS2 random-float 7.0                                                       
     set shape "person"
  ]

end

...

to-report AEC_treatment_time ;; gamma dist                                           

  let los-AEC AEC-los                                                                

  if los-AEC < 2  [ report 2 ]                                                       
  if los-AEC > 20 [ report 20]

  report los-AEC

end

to-report AMU_treatment_time ; gamma dist                                            ;; reports treatment time for patients in AMU

  let los-AMU AMU-los                                                                

  if los-AMU < 4  [ report 4]
  if los-AMU > 48 [ report 48]

  report los-AMU

end
```

ps trying multiple iterations, it seems to be the random-poisson change that is the one causing the issues

Comment: please show the code for the new assess procedure. Also, what did you do with the code that is applied to your newly sprouted turtles (in the [ ] immediately after sprout in your original code)?

Comment: thanks JenB. Updated as requested. The new assess procedure has the original instructions. I've also (incidentally) realised that I can't truncate the gamma dists to created a location parameter - just in case anyone spots that. Changing them to dists without limits makes no difference to the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to see without the full code as it looks to be a problem with the way procedures connect, but your new structure has `ask patients-here` (at the start of the assess procedure) inside a loop through `ask arrivals` (go procedure). Is arrivals a breed?

Generally it is a bad thing to have nested `ask turtles` type structures because each turtle ask all turtles that satisfy the conditions so you can get subtle errors. Anyway, this will probably get you back to what you were doing before:

```
to go
  if ticks = 1000 [stop]
  ask arrivals                                   
  [ sprout-patients new-patients [assess]                                       
    crowding-check                               
    relocate                                     
  ]
 end

to assess                                                                             
  set time_arrived ticks                                                           
  set condition random-float 1.0                                                   
  set NEWS2 random-float 7.0                                                       
  set shape "person"
end
```

This structure makes the assess procedure into a procedure that runs from the turtle's perspective (or context) and has it run immediately as the turtle calling it is created.

Comment: Thanks JenB. This looked really promising as I did wonder if the commandos were juts too many steps removed. Still doesn't like it though...

Comment: I'll keep having a think about it. arrivals is a patch. there's not much more to the code that informs this so I wonder if it's just something I'll have to keep in the procedure. No hardship just thought it made it a bit easier on the eye and to manipulate

Comment: I should have realised arrivals are patches - otherwise `sprout` would throw an error. You might have to go back to standard debugging methods and add something like `print new-patients` inside the a`ask arrivals` block to check it has the value you expect.